# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, backbone.js

I'm getting undefined error while checking length. Please look at picture

[image]

```
this. updateConfiguration = _.debounce(this.updateConfiguration, 300); 
 this.set({ url: (HyprLiveContext.locals.siteContext.siteSubdirectory 11 ") + (slug ? "/" + slug : "") + "/p/" + this.get("productCode)} 
 this.lastConfiguration = []; 
 this.calculateHasPriceRange(conf); conf = undefined 
 this.on('sync', this.calculateHasPriceRange); 
 var variations = this.get('variations'); variations = undefined 
 var sum = 0; sum = 0 

 !.. 0) 
  { 
  var stockArray = []; 

  for(var 1=0; i<variations.length; i++) 
  {
```

what could be the reason?

Comment: Post your full code with HTML context here.

Comment: We do not want to look at images for code. Please post the section of code into your post. Without looking some variable is undefined, so you need to figure out why it was not set.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the help pages, especially the sections named "What topics can I ask about here?" and "What types of questions should I avoid asking?". Also please take the tour and read about how to ask good questions. Lastly please learn how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example

Comment: Hi, Please take a moment to look at [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It will help people if you provide an example of your code rather than an image here.

Comment: [Do not post images of code or errors!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Answer (score -1):

Try initializing the array, and checking for a truthy value:

```
var variations = [];

if (this.get('variations')) {
    variations = this.get('variations');
}
```

Comment: That makes little sense in JavaScript. Whatever `this.get('variations')` returns will override what you did previously.

Comment: There's no length of undefined, if you initialize it's an empty array with has a length of 0? Maybe use a conditional in the initialization if this isn't suitable for JavaScript.

Comment: But when `this.get` returns undefined, it will still be undefined.... It is not going to magically know that it once was an array when it is replaced with that get call returns. Not knowing what `.get()` is, makes answering this question nearly impossible.

Comment: Changed to check for truthy value, bit harsh on the downvotes, just trying to help.